# Call method just before storing object in datastore (GAE)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

is there any possibility to call method just before making object persistent?
Something like "onMakeObjectPersistent()"

I want to calculate geohash basing on lon and lat and store it in datastore.

Regars,
M

**Solution:**

as @Duy Do post:
in JDO we can do that using jdoPreStore() method:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Foo implements StoreCallback{
    public void jdoPreStore()
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not use GAE but I think if you use JPA you can use PrePesist annotation along with method you want to call before the object is persisted. With JDO you can use method jdoPreStore().